# How to plot a boxplot from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a nested dictionary, a subset of which is given below:

```
dict_a = {
    '2019': {
        'Jan-Mar': {
            'category_A': [0.0, 11.344454217292942, 4.885790495524913], 
            'category_B': [0.0, 14.657371486574736, 0.0, 4.885790495524913]
            },
        'Apr-June': {
            'category_A': [4.885790495524913, 0.0, 7.7437947217868235, 7.7437947217868235],
            'category_B': [7.7437947217868235, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
            }
            },
    '2020': {
        'Jan-Mar': {
            'category_A': [7.7437947217868235, 7.7437947217868235, 21.787848617781385],
            'category_B': [4.885790495524913, 4.885790495524913, 0.0, 7.7437947217868235]
            },
        'Apr-June': {
            'category_A': [0.0, 11.344454217292942, 0.0, 7.7437947217868235], 
            'category_B': [4.885790495524913, 0.0, 4.885790495524913]
            }
            }
}
```

I am trying to plot a boxplot of the data for a given category, such that the x axis is the month group (e.g. 'Jan-Mar') and the legend shows the year (e.g. '2019') for each box. For instance, for category_A, I would have two boxplots per month group, each corresponding to a given year, with a legend displaying the year for each box.

I have tried converting the dictionary to a pandas dataframe but have struggled with multiindex plotting. I would like to know if there is a far simpler method using the original dictionary. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For boxplots with many dimensions, seaborn's `sns.catplot` is handy. Seaborn prefers its data as a dataframe in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data). Such a dataframe can be created from the given dictionary via nested `for` loops. (This would also work when the categories would have a different number of values.)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_a = {'2019': {'Jan-Mar': {'category_A': [0.0, 11.344454217292942, 4.885790495524913], 'category_B': [0.0, 14.657371486574736, 0.0, 4.885790495524913]}, 'Apr-June': {'category_A': [4.885790495524913, 0.0, 7.7437947217868235, 7.7437947217868235], 'category_B': [7.7437947217868235, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}}, '2020': {'Jan-Mar': {'category_A': [7.7437947217868235, 7.7437947217868235, 21.787848617781385], 'category_B': [4.885790495524913, 4.885790495524913, 0.0, 7.7437947217868235]}, 'Apr-June': {'category_A': [0.0, 11.344454217292942, 0.0, 7.7437947217868235], 'category_B': [4.885790495524913, 0.0, 4.885790495524913]}}}

df = pd.DataFrame()
for year, months_groups in dict_a.items():
    for months, cat_groups in months_groups.items():
        for cat, values in cat_groups.items():
            df_cat = pd.DataFrame({'val': values})
            df_cat['cat'] = cat
            df_cat['months'] = months
            df_cat['year'] = year
            df = df.append(df_cat, ignore_index=True)
g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='box', x='months', y='val', hue='year', col='cat',
                height=5, aspect=1.2, palette='spring')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot from nested dictionary]

Seaborn lets you easily experiment exchanging the roles of `x=`, `hue=`, `col=` and/or `row=`. It also lets you try out [different kinds of plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) (e.g. `kind='violin'`).

Comment: This is spot on. Exactly what I was looking for. I will take a look at the seaborn catplot docs. Thanks!